# How to convert from int to int?, in C#?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a `int` i want to save as a `int?` 
Is it possible and if so how?

Comment: Save? Where? Consider adding *a little more* (e.g. any) context to your question.

Comment: Well I tryed this                     `int? status2 = new Nullable<int>(someThing);` The idea was actually not all that bad, I can see now that it work. I just had a error with the someThing, and I thought the error was the new Nullable<int> code I used. So I tricked my self :(

Comment: someThing come from a textbox. I don't remember the error but i think i was a parsing error or another error higher up in the code that confused me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's an implicit conversion:

```
int nonNullable = 5;
int? nullable = nonNullable;
```

(This is given in section 6.1.4 of the C# specification.)

The reverse operation is unsafe, of course, because the nullable value could be null. There's an explicit conversion, or you can use the `Value` property:

```
int? nullable = new int?(5); // Just to be clear :)

// These are equivalent
int nonNullable1 = (int) nullable;
int nonNullable2 = nullable.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks to you and Øyvind for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This goes automatic. Lets say you have the following int

```
int myInt = 5;
```

Then you can write the following without problems:

```
int? myNullableInt = myInt;
```